# Issue with displaying the cart totals

Tags: cart, price

In my cart page i am trying to alter the styles of total price displayed

```
frontend\base\default\template\checkout/cart/totals.phtml

frontend\base\default\template\tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml

frontend\base\default\template\tax/checkout/subtotal.phtml
```

These templates displays the subtotal and grand total.

```
<tfoot>
            <?php echo $this->renderTotals('footer'); ?>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <?php echo $this->renderTotals(); ?>
        </tbody>
```

This is the default phtml. The `<tfoot>` appears on first followed by `<tbody>` but in browser the `<tfoot>` appears after `<tbody>` .

I was trying to modify the htmls for displaying this, but the pbm i facing is grand total appears above sub total.

How to make grand total appear after sub total?

Answer (score 2):

So you've stumbled on one of the fun parts of Magento...

And by fun I mean it is very challenging to customize.

You'll want to look at: Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Totals

the "renderTotals(" function...

```
 $html = '';
        foreach($this->getTotals() as $total) {
            if ($total->getArea() != $area && $area != -1) {
                continue;
            }
            $html .= $this->renderTotal($total, $area, $colspan);
        }
        return $html;
```

The $this->getTotals() call returns and ordered array, so in order to change the order on the front end you need to add logic that Sorts the array before this foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

It is HTML standard to show the table in this order:

```
table
    thead
    tbody (if any)
    tfoot
```

Therefore if you remove the `<tfoot>` (and `<tbody>`) it might fix your problem.

Comment: It doesn't matter that tfoot is after tbody, it displays the same order.

Comment: Correct, tfoot is always shown after the tbody but if you remove the tbody and only left the `<tr>`s it should have the order in the HTML